# What is the significance of '+' in this statement. if [[ ${array1[$i]+DEFINED} == 'DEFINED' ]]

Tags: shell-script

What is the significance of "+" in the following `for` loop:

```
for i in $*;do
  if [[ ${array1[$i]+DEFINED} == 'DEFINED' ]];then
    command1
  fi
done
```

Comment: That's the "Use Alternate Value" parameter expansion (c.f. `man bash`)

Comment: Regarding `$*`.  This should probably be `"$@"`. `$*` would expand to the unquoted string consisting of the positional parameters joined by the first character of `$IFS` (this would then undergo word splitting and filename globbing).  `"$@"` would expand to the _individually quoted_ positional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion in the manual.

if that variable has a value, substitute the word "DEFINED", else if the variable is unset, substitute nothing.

```
$ unset foo; echo ">${foo+DEFINED}<"
><
$ foo=""; echo ">${foo+DEFINED}<"
>DEFINED<
$ foo=bar; echo ">${foo+DEFINED}<"
>DEFINED<
```

Your code looks like there is an associative array `array1`, and you are iterating over the positional parameters to do something with some of the array values.

```
# set up the array
declare -A array1
array1[abc]=first
array1[def]=second
array1[ghi]=third
# set the positional parameters
set -- ghi abc

for i in "$@"; do
  if [[ ${array1[$i]+DEFINED} == 'DEFINED' ]]; then
    echo "found $i -> ${array1[$i]}"
  fi
done
```

```
found ghi -> third
found abc -> first
```

Comment: Also, [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).